# Is decent HTTPs implementation for medium public site always a paid solution?

Tags: html, security, ssl, https

I'm aware that for adding HTTPs to a site, one can either:

1. buy a overpriced SSL certificate from a reputed CA like
   VeriSign
2. or purchase a much lower priced certificate from several
   other companies
3. or one could even use his/her own self signed
   certificate i.e, for free.

But for a decent HTTPs implementation that is:

1. you want **most of standard browsers recognize the certificate**(there shouldn't be any warnings/ errors on standard browsers)
2. **security is tight rather than just a false impression** of secure site.
3. **brand name of CA is not that really important** to you.
4. for a public site similar to LinkedIn but smaller in scale(no financial transactions, but users profile data).
5. **economical pricing**

Would implementing such an HTTPs always come at a price ? What is the cost effective way to implement it ? I don't want to spend hundred of dollars an year initially, when I have lower user base.

Comment: downvoter may kindly leave a comment.

Comment: I assume the downvote comes from the fact that your question is off topic because it is business related, not of a technical nature.

Comment: In my case it is because of the tendentious and irrelevant statement 'highly overrated'.

Comment: @EJP: sorry I didn't meant that exactly. Fixed now!

Comment: 'Overpriced' is also tendentious and irrelevant, and unsupported. Downvote remains.

Comment: @EJP: okay, but that's my opinion.

Comment: The warning for self-signed certificates has a reason. Without a signature from a 3rd party, it is possible for a man-in-the-middle to swap the certificate with an own and then take the role of a transparent proxy and eavesdrop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) offers certificates at prices based on the effort it takes to validate the data that you want to have validated, rather than based on the added value percieved by the customer. As a result, domain validated certificates are free, because validation can be fully automated. These kinds of certificates ensure that the client is talking to the domain advertised in the common name, rather than to some man-in-the-middle or some host that the domain resolves to as a result of DNS poisoning.

None of the personal information that you provide will be available in a domain validated certificate. If it would, than it would imply that the CA actually validated that information.

For a lot of sites, this is enough security. For shops, banks and other sites that require certain personal information from the client, this is clearly not enough. These sites should use certificates that not only ensure that the user communicates with the site that he wants to, but also that the site is run by the company that he wants to do business with.

Comment: very helpful! exactly the kind of response I was looking for.. I think free version would be fine for me. Do you know of other companies that have similar kind offers ? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any other company with a similar business model. [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/) provides certificates based on a web-of-trust, but AFAIK the CA certificate is not included in the major browsers, leading to the same problems that a self-signed certificate has.